# How to get an R^2 and P-Value for R ELISA Analysis 4PL

Tags: r, curve-fitting, p-value, sigmoid

I am trying to mimic the graphpad ELISA analysis using R, however I am having a bit of difficulty getting a P-Value and an R^2 value.

I have followed the tutorial: http://weightinginbayesianmodels.github.io/poctcalibration/calib_tut4_curve_ocon.html#unweighted-nonlinear-regression-in-r

It got me a majority of the information needed using a package called "minpack.lm", however I am not sure how to approach getting the R^2 and P value from here.

```
  ODCalc1 <- c(.007, .072, .328, .988, 1.534, 1.983)
  ODCalc2 <- c(.006, .074, .361, .858, 1.612, 1.993)
  ODCalc <- (ODCalc1 + ODCalc2)/2

  concentration <- log10(c(1, 36, 180, 540, 1080, 1800))

  ocon <- data.frame(10^(concentration), "rep", ODCalc, stringsAsFactors = F)
  ocon$X.rep. <- as.numeric(ocon$X.rep.)
  ocon$X.rep. <- 1
  names(ocon) <- c("conc", "rep", "od")

  # Plot the O'Connell data
  par(mfrow = c(1, 2), cex.main = 1, mar = c(4, 4, 1, 2), oma = c(0.5, 0.5, 2.5, 0))
  plot(ocon$conc, ocon$od, pch = 21, bg = "grey", ylab = "Response (od)", 
       xlab = "Concentration")
  grid()
  # Plot on the log(x) scale
  plot(log(ocon$conc), ocon$od, pch = 21, bg = "grey", ylab = "Response (od)", 
       xlab = "log(concentration)")
  grid()
  title("O'Connell's ELISA: concentration on absolute (left) and log (right) scales",
        outer = T)

  par(mfrow = c(1, 1))

  # ------------ Function: 4PL curve function ---------------------------------  
  M.4pl <- function(x, small.x.asymp, inf.x.asymp, inflec, hill){
    f <- small.x.asymp + ((inf.x.asymp - small.x.asymp)/
                            (1 + (x / inflec)^hill))
    return(f)
  }
  # ------------- end ---------------------------------------------------------

  start.ocon <- c(small.x.asymp = 0.1, inf.x.asymp = 1, inflec = 3000, hill = -1)
  library(minpack.lm)
  uw.4pl <- nlsLM(od ~ M.4pl(conc, small.x.asymp, inf.x.asymp, inflec, hill), 
                  data = ocon,
                  start = start.ocon)
  data.4pl <- summary(uw.4pl)

  bottom.4pl <- data.4pl$parameters[1,1]
  top.4pl <- data.4pl$parameters[2,1]
  IC50.4pl <- data.4pl$parameters[3,1]
  HillSlope.4pl <- abs(data.4pl$parameters[4,1])

  RSS.p <- sum(residuals(uw.4pl)^2)
  TSS <- sum((ocon$od - mean(ocon$od))^2)
  r.squared <- 1-(RSS.p/TSS) # is this the proper way to get an r^2 value? It does not match what graphpad has which is an issue.

  # I have also read this should work, but since the model is a linear model instead of a Sigmoidal, 4PL, X is log (concentration) model
  model <- lm(concentration ~ poly(ODCalc, degree = 4, raw=T))
  summary(model) # R^2 is not the correct value I am looking for.

  # Not sure if sample data is needed but these were the values we were using to produce the values below
  sample.od.values1 <- c(0.275, 1.18, 0.085, 0.054, 0.119)
  sample.od.values2 <- c(0.263, 1.149, 0.068, 0.062, 0.109)
  sample.od.values <- (sample.od.values1+sample.od.values2)/2
```

Values to prove the methods are the same:

**bottom.4pl = 0.01657**

**top.4pl = 3.002**

**HillSlope = 1.222**

**R^2 = 0.9978**

**R^2(adjusted) = 0.9969**

**P-Value = 0.5106**

Thank you in advance for any helpful tips!

Comment: I don't know about R^2 and p, but the parameter values are correct in model uw.4pl. Run "summary(uw.4pl)" and look at the estimate values for small.x.asymp, inf.x.asymp, and hill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since R^2 measures linear association it is normally used for linear regression but ignoring that this seems to give the numbers you want or at least numbers that are close to those.  For the adjusted R squared formula see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2 and for the p-value I have assumed that you are looking for the p-value for the hypothesis that the first coefficient is zero.

```
RSS <- deviance(uw.4pl); RSS
## [1] 0.001514624

coef(uw.4pl) # coefficients/parameters
## small.x.asymp   inf.x.asymp        inflec          hill 
##    0.01654996    3.00261439 1033.53324214   -1.22171740 

R2 <- cor(ocon$od, fitted(uw.4pl))^2; R2
## [1] 0.9995529

n <- nobs(uw.4pl)    
p <- length(coef(uw.4pl))
adjR2 <- 1 - (1-R2) * (n - 1) / (n - p - 1); adjR2
## [1] 0.9977645

pvalue <- coef(summary(uw.4pl))[1, 4]; pvalue
## [1] 0.5486584
```

Comment: Thank you for this, helped me a bit more, however now how do I predict the values for the samples run on the ELISA once you have all of these values?

Comment: Tryy `?predict.nls`